# Computing Tamagawa number of torus in Quaternion algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, quaternions, adeles

Consider a rational Quaternion algebra $M$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that does not split at $\infty$. For example take the rational Hamilton quaternions $M=\mathbb{Q}(-1,-1)$.
For the adele ring $\mathbb{A}$ we define $M(\mathbb{A}):= M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{A}$ and $G=G(\mathbb{A}):= M(\mathbb{A})^\times / \mathbb{A}^\times$. Analogous we can define $G(\mathbb{Q})$. This is then a cocompact lattice in $G$. For a $\gamma \in G(\mathbb{Q})$ we can consider the centralizer $G_\gamma$ of $\gamma $ in $G$. If $\gamma$ is a generic semisimple element and I am not mistaken, $G_\gamma$ is an algebraic torus defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is there a way to compute the Tamagawa number of these tori? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should look at Vignéras, Arithmétique des Algèbres de Quaternions. A lot of computations are done there. I believe there is a translated version available online. A good part of this book can be found in Maclachlan and Reid, The Arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-manifolds

Comment: What does "generic" mean?  Your element $\gamma$ is an element of the quaternion algebra (up to rescaling), and so if $\gamma \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{Q}[\gamma] = K$ is an imaginary quadratic field.  What is the role of the quaternion algebra here?  Every imaginary quadratic field with the property that $2$ is not split in $K$ arises this way, so your question is about $K^\times/\mathbb{Q}^\times$ for these fields?  My basic understanding is that the Tamagawa number is given by a class number, is that what you're after?

Comment: Tam = Pic / Sha, src = Ono.  :)

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus Thanks, I will have a close look at Vignéras (or rather the translation).

Comment: @JohnVoight I need the quaternion algebra as I am interested in the centralizer $G_\gamma$. This can be larger than $\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]$. By generic I mean elements unlike $\gamma=1$ for which the centralizer is the whole Quaternion algebra.

Comment: @Marty I also found Tam=Pic/Sha. But how to compute Pic or Sha in this setting?

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus IIRC, Maclachlan and Reid do not do Tamagawa numbers, and I think Vigneras does Tamagawa numbers of norm 1 subgroups of quaternion algebras and quadratic fields, but not the quotient by the base field which will give you the factor of 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some more details.  As John Voight said, the quaternion algebra is kind of irrelevant here.  If $\gamma$ is a regular semisimple element, then its centralizer is a torus ${\mathbf T}$ over ${\mathbb Q}$ satisfying
$${\mathbf T}({\mathbb Q}) = K^\times / {\mathbb Q}^\times,$$
where $K = {\mathbb Q}(\gamma)$ is the centralizer of $\gamma$ in the quaternion algebra.  In terms of algebraic groups, ${\mathbf T}$ fits into a short exact sequence of tori,
$$1 \rightarrow {\mathbf G}_m \rightarrow {\mathbf R}_{K/{\mathbb Q}} {\mathbf G}_m \rightarrow {\mathbf T} \rightarrow 1.$$

There aren't too many rank-one tori.  Since ${\mathbf T}$ is nonsplit, the character lattice of ${\mathbf T}$ is ${\mathbb Z}$, with the unique nontrivial action of $Gal(K/{\mathbb Q})$.  Thus ${\mathbf T}$ is also isomorphic to the norm-one torus ${\mathbf R}_{K/{\mathbb Q}}^1 {\mathbf G}_m$.

It happens that norm-one tori arising from cyclic extensions have trivial Sha.  This is in Platonov and Rapinchuk, I think, and probably goes back to Tate or something.  The basic idea is that Sha captures the failure of the Hasse principle.  In the context above,
$$Sha({\mathbf T}) \cong \frac{\left( {\mathbb Q}^\times \cap N_{K/{\mathbb Q}} {\mathbb A}_K^\times \right) }{ N_{K / {\mathbb Q}} K^\times}.$$
This is trivial, by the Hasse Norm Theorem (since $K / {\mathbb Q}$ is cyclic).

So we have 
$$Tam({\mathbf T}) = \frac{\# Pic({\mathbf T})}{\# Sha({\mathbf T})} = \# Pic({\mathbf T}).$$

Explicitly, the Picard group $Pic({\mathbf T})$ in this context is the group $H^1(Gal(K/{\mathbb Q}), {\mathbb Z})$, where the order-two Galois group acts by the nontrivial automorphism.  This is a group of order two.  Hence
$$Tam({\mathbf T}) = 2.$$